# Microsoft Graph API FindRooms ErrorAccessDenied

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We are trying to fetch a list of rooms in the organization via [user_findrooms](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_findrooms) on the beta API.

I am using the [php-connect-sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/php-connect-sample) and was directed here after creating an  [issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/php-connect-sample/issues/9) there.

Our application is registered, and has the required permissions. The user is logged in and redirected correctly. I can successfully get the `/me` endpoint

When I try to get the `/me/findRooms` endpoint like this:

```
$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setApiVersion('beta');
$graph->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

$rooms = $graph->createRequest("get", "/me/findRooms")
                        ->setReturnType(Model\EmailAddress::class)
                        ->execute();
```

Then I get the following error:

> Client error: GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/findRooms
>   resulted in a 403 Forbidden response: { "error": { "code":
>   "ErrorAccessDenied", "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials
>   and try again.", (truncated...)

So it seems to be a permissions error.

We have the following Graph permissions for our app:

**Delegated Permissions**: `User.ReadBasic.All` and `User.Read.All`

**Application Permissions**: `Calendars.ReadWrite` and `User.Read.All`

Which additional permissions are required to access `/me/findRooms`?

Comment: If you're only running this in the presence of a user, you don't need to specify app permissions. It looks like the delegated permissions you defined are sufficient to query for rooms on the beta endpoint, but there is some other auth issue going on. For additional context: are you using [AAD V2 auth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-scopes)? Also, if you [decode your token](http://jwt.calebb.net/), what do you see in the 'scp' collection?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @DmitryPimenov

Yes, I am using the Azure AD v2.0 endpoint to get the oauth token

When I decode the token it contains the following under scp:
`"Calendars.ReadWrite User.Read"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your auth flow, you will need to specify User.Read.All instead of User.Read in your scopes since this API requires reading all users in your directory to find conference room availabilities. [Here is more information about how to request such scopes during the /authorize and /token requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-scopes).

Comment: Thanks. I had this permission in the app, but did not pass it along with the scopes.

Comment: User.ReadBasic.All works too if you don't have User.Read.All available